# How can I see the file structure in Docker-Windows?

Tags: windows, docker

I would like to see file structure like Docker-linux that using below syntax:

```
docker exec -it <container id> bash
```

However, now I am using Windows10 with Docker-windows. I tried below syntax but fail:

```
docker exec -it <container id> bash
docker exec -it <container id> sh
docker exec -it <container id> //bin/bash
```

Error like:

> Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] extra info: {"CommandLine":"//bin/bash","WorkingDirectory":"C:\App","EmulateConsole":true,"CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0]}

Comment: I think you need powershell `docker exec -it <container id> powershell`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use PowerShell, as the container is based on the window, not Linux.

```
docker exec -it <container id> powershell
```